# Why do I get high latency for small number of kafka producers and small latency (RTT) for big number of kafka producers?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I run 3 Kafka brokers and spark ( master = local[8]) on a pc, where I wrote java code to subscribe a Kafka topic "A", process and publish to a Kafka topic "B". And run 4 Kafka producers that publish to the topic "A" and one Kafka consumer that subscribe to a topic "B" using java on another pc.

I calculated the RTT in the Kafka consumer code.

***The problem is:*** when I increase the number of Kafka Producers I get lower RTTs!!!.

I tried to change batch.size increase and decrease but it didn't work.

***Kafka producer configuration:***

```
        //If acks=0, then the producer will not wait for any acknowledgment from the server at all.
        props.put("acks", "0");
        props.put("client.id", "vehicleProducer");
        props.put("retries", 0);
        props.put("batch.size", 50);
        props.put("linger.ms", 0);
        props.put("buffer.memory", 1024);
        props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.IntegerSerializer");
        props.put("value.serializer", "com.iov.safety.fullvehicleproducer.CarFullDataSerializer");
```

***Kafka Consumer configuration:***

```
        props.put("group.id", "test");
        props.put("enable.auto.commit", "true");
        props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "1000");
        props.put("session.timeout.ms", "30000");
        props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
```

***Kafka Spark Consumer configuration:***

```
        kafkaParams.put("bootstrap.servers", BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_RSU2_EDUROAM);
        kafkaParams.put("key.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class);
        kafkaParams.put("value.deserializer", CarDataDeserializer.class);
        kafkaParams.put("group.id", "test-consumer-group");
        kafkaParams.put("auto.offset.reset", "latest");
        kafkaParams.put("enable.auto.commit", false);
```

I expect that increasing the number of producers should increase RTT from Kafka consumer side.

Comment: I'd suggest connecting via jconsole or jvisualvm to both consumers and producer and looking at detailed Kafka stats under load via JMX beans.

Comment: IMO it's most probably batching. Try setting batch size to 1 and see if RTT stays the same. Also I'd try to simplify the task and narrow your measuring only to Producer -> Consumer1 and see if you still see decrease in RTT that you described.

Comment: Isn't setting batch size to 1 means send 1 byte per message?

Comment: you are right, I haven't touched Kafka for a long time. Sorry about that. What I meant was to disable batching entirely. "linger.ms = 0" does that.

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't work with me. Is there other configs could affect the performance?

Comment: What do you want low latency? Or throughput?

Comment: Actually, these are interesting questions..
1. If I want to get high throughput (i.e. handling an increasing amount of data, big data), what to consider in the configuration?
2. to get high throughput in realtime, what to change?